# Processing AndroidAnnotations with Maven fails, if not using the FQPN but import statement of a class instead

Tags: android, maven, android-annotations

Processing AndroidAnnotations with Maven (3.0.3) fails, if not using the FQPN but an import statement of a class instead:

This fails:

**Note the difference in using the import vs. FQPN in the code, for the reference to the App class, "delta" in my case.**

```
import com.my_project.delta.android.Delta_;

/**
 * Splash screen with logo.
 */
@EActivity(R.layout.act_splash)
public class Splash extends BaseActivity {

    /**
     * Reference to application.
     */
    @App
    protected Delta_ delta;
```

while this works fine:

```
/**
 * Splash screen with logo.
 */
@EActivity(R.layout.act_splash)
public class Splash extends BaseActivity {

    /**
     * Reference to application.
     */
    @App
    protected com.my_project.delta.android.Delta_ delta;
```

Error as below:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project com.my_project.delta.android: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/user/Projects/My-Project/delta-android/target/generated-sources/annotations/com/my_project/delta/android/activity/Splash_.java:[29,19] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   class Delta_
[ERROR] location: class com.my_project.delta.android.activity.Splash_
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

pom.xml: http://pastebin.com/HhxCVYmN

A bug in AndroidAnnotations maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see your using the 3.0-SNAPSHOT version.
Can you tell me which commit you used to compile the library ?
this might be an issue with the last implemented feature.

EDIT: Just saw that your using the generated class. Can you try with this :

```
@App
Delta delta;
```

Comment: It happens both with AA 2.7 and 3.0-SNAPSHOT. Interestingly though, I can reference to generated activities, for example: Login_.intent(this).start(); from within my Splash activity.... therefore I am wondering, why am I not able to reference to the generated Application activity (Delta_) but need to reference the original one instead.

Comment: (I didn't compile the library myself.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know well enough the core of AndroidAnnotation to answer to your question. For now, I suspect EActivity to be processed before EApplication. So the generated App is unknown from the activity at this moment. It's on my todo list to  completely understand this part :)